# Why are my Starfruits not growing?

Tags: stardew-valley

I planted some Starfruit in the greenhouse on the first day of summer. It is now the sixteenth day and nothing has happened. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 8):

Crops in the greenhouse need to be watered just like crops outside. Make sure you water your Starfruit.